# Embedding a JavaScript canvas into the python TKinter

Tags: javascript, python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to embed a JavaScript canvas into the python Tkinter. I hope when I opened the GUI I will see the Javascript canvas already on the interface, is it possible to just import the JavaScript codes directly into the python script? Thank you.

Comment: please add some code or print screen?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to use javascript to draw in a Tkinter canvas.